# When Trying to Build an Xcode project from unity to my iPhone it gives me this error Apple Mach-O Linker (Id) Error

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine, linker, mach-o

It also says ”Linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)”

Here is the whole error thing.

Ld /Users/josephrabinowitz/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-dbekdbzoohacbgbjowjloajibhch/Build/Products/ReleaseForRunning-iphoneos/ProductName.app/ProductName normal arm64
    cd "/Volumes/Lexar/New folder"
    export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=8.0
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang++ -arch arm64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS11.2.sdk -L/Users/josephrabinowitz/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-dbekdbzoohacbgbjowjloajibhch/Build/Products/ReleaseForRunning-iphoneos -L/Volumes/Lexar/New\ folder -L/Volumes/Lexar/New\ folder/Libraries -F/Users/josephrabinowitz/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-dbekdbzoohacbgbjowjloajibhch/Build/Products/ReleaseForRunning-iphoneos -F/Volumes/Lexar/New\ folder/Frameworks/Plugins/iOS -F/Volumes/Lexar/New\ folder/UnityAds -filelist /Users/josephrabinowitz/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-dbekdbzoohacbgbjowjloajibhch/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Unity-iPhone.build/ReleaseForRunning-iphoneos/Unity-iPhone.build/Objects-normal/arm64/ProductName.LinkFileList -Xlinker -map -Xlinker /Users/josephrabinowitz/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-dbekdbzoohacbgbjowjloajibhch/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Unity-iPhone.build/ReleaseForRunning-iphoneos/Unity-iPhone.build/ProductName-LinkMap-normal-arm64.txt -miphoneos-version-min=8.0 -dead_strip -Xlinker -object_path_lto -Xlinker /Users/josephrabinowitz/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-dbekdbzoohacbgbjowjloajibhch/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Unity-iPhone.build/ReleaseForRunning-iphoneos/Unity-iPhone.build/Objects-normal/arm64/ProductName_lto.o -fembed-bitcode-marker -stdlib=libc++ -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -weak_framework CoreMotion -weak-lSystem -framework MediaToolbox -liPhone-lib -framework CoreText -framework AudioToolbox -weak_framework AVFoundation -framework CFNetwork -framework CoreGraphics -framework CoreLocation -framework CoreMedia -weak_framework CoreMotion -framework CoreVideo -framework Foundation -framework MediaPlayer -framework OpenAL -framework OpenGLES -framework QuartzCore -framework SystemConfiguration -framework UIKit -liconv.2 -lil2cpp -framework UnityAds -weak_framework Metal -framework UnityAds -weak_framework AdSupport -framework StoreKit -framework CoreTelephony -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/josephrabinowitz/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-dbekdbzoohacbgbjowjloajibhch/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Unity-iPhone.build/ReleaseForRunning-iphoneos/Unity-iPhone.build/Objects-normal/arm64/ProductName_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/josephrabinowitz/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-dbekdbzoohacbgbjowjloajibhch/Build/Products/ReleaseForRunning-iphoneos/ProductName.app/ProductName

duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_UnityAdsUnityWrapperDelegate in:
    /Users/josephrabinowitz/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-dbekdbzoohacbgbjowjloajibhch/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Unity-iPhone.build/ReleaseForRunning-iphoneos/Unity-iPhone.build/Objects-normal/arm64/UnityAdsUnityWrapper-6D362980BD529555.o
    /Users/josephrabinowitz/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-dbekdbzoohacbgbjowjloajibhch/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Unity-iPhone.build/ReleaseForRunning-iphoneos/Unity-iPhone.build/Objects-normal/arm64/UnityAdsUnityWrapper-6341A35D92B36E50.o
duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_UnityAdsUnityWrapperDelegate in:
    /Users/josephrabinowitz/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-dbekdbzoohacbgbjowjloajibhch/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Unity-iPhone.build/ReleaseForRunning-iphoneos/Unity-iPhone.build/Objects-normal/arm64/UnityAdsUnityWrapper-6D362980BD529555.o
    /Users/josephrabinowitz/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-dbekdbzoohacbgbjowjloajibhch/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Unity-iPhone.build/ReleaseForRunning-iphoneos/Unity-iPhone.build/Objects-normal/arm64/UnityAdsUnityWrapper-6341A35D92B36E50.o
ld: 3 duplicate symbols for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Anybody know why this is happening?